# Java 8 lambdas execution

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, functional-interface

How can I do something like this in Java 8?

```
boolean x = ((boolean p)->{return p;}).apply(true);
```

Right now I get the following error:

> The target type of this expression must be a functional interface

Comment: The examples I can see do not use {}, since it is meant to be a single statement. [Tutorial](http://winterbe.com/posts/2014/03/16/java-8-tutorial/)

Comment: Same thing without a {} around return p. I dont think so that is the problem.

Comment: Your mistake is in assuming that `Function` has any special status so that the lambda's type would be automatically coerced into it. Your expression has in fact no target type constraint.

Comment: You can fix the code by telling the compiler the type for the lambda:
boolean x = ((Function<Boolean, Boolean>) p->p).apply(true);

Answer (score 28, accepted):

As per the JLS [section 15.27](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27):

> It is a compile-time error if a lambda expression occurs in a program in someplace other than an assignment context (§5.2), an invocation context (§5.3), or a casting context (§5.5).

It is also possible to use a lambda expression in a [`return` statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.17).

We can then rewrite your example in four different ways:

- By creating an assignment context:

  ```
  Function<Boolean, Boolean> function = p -> p;
  boolean x = function.apply(true);
  ```
- By creating an invocation context:

  ```
  foobar(p -> p);

  private static void foobar(Function<Boolean, Boolean> function) {
      boolean x = function.apply(true);
  }
  ```
- By creating a casting context:

  ```
  boolean x = ((Function<Boolean, Boolean>) p -> p).apply(true);
  ```
- Using a `return` statement:

  ```
  boolean x = function().apply(true);

  private static Function<Boolean, Boolean> function() {
      return p -> p;
  }
  ```

Also, in this simple example, the whole lambda expression can be rewritten as:

```
UnaryOperator<Boolean> function = UnaryOperator.identity();
```